# Will Color Swatches Migrated during Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1 Migration?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, color-swatches, magento2-migration-tool

I am planning to migrate my site from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1. I have a question that I have color swatches on my current site so If I will migrate using Uber Migration tool, Then Can I use those color swatches in Magento-2.1 also?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I run across your question a bit late.

For color swatches, it would be best to proceed on case by case basis, if you use our [UB Data Migration](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-pro/) tool.

As you know the color swatches associate with both text, visual (including color, image) swatches, and the way Magento 2 handle color swatches differ from Magento 1. Our migration tool helps to bring all text color swatches to M2, however for visual color swatches, it will need additional configuration steps to make it ready for use in M2.

If you need our help on this, feel free to reach us [here](https://www.ubertheme.com/questions/).

Regards,
Ubertheme team